# Null values stored in table via Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Following is my stored procedure which stores data in two tables namely SuccessfulLogins and FailedLogins

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Proc_CheckUser]
 @UserID   VARCHAR(50),
 @Password VARCHAR(50)
 AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @PasswordOld VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @IP  NVARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @PasswordOld = Password,@Type=ClientType,@IP=IPAddress
    FROM   Clients
    WHERE  Username = @userid 

    IF (@PasswordOld IS NULL)
      BEGIN
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'
      INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password),@Type,'Invalid Username',@IP)
      END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
    IF (@PasswordOld!=Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password))
      BEGIN
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Password'
      INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password),@Type,'Invalid Password',@IP)
      END

      ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully' +'|'+ rtrim(cast(@Type as char))
      INSERT INTO SuccessfulLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
      VALUES(@UserID,Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password),@Type,'Valid Login Credentials    Provided',@IP)
      END 
      END

      SELECT @ReturnVal
```

The problem here is that whenever I enter an Invalid Username,the stored procedure returns the correct message ie Incorrect Username but it stores NULL values in the fields ClientType and IPAddress in Failed Logins Table

Following is my insert query for Invalid username

```
IF (@PasswordOld!=Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password))
BEGIN
SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Password'
INSERT INTO FailedLogins(Username,Password,ClientType,Reason,IPAddress)
VALUES(@UserID,Hashbytes('SHA1',@Password),@Type,'Invalid Password',@IP)
END
```

Can anyone help me to rectify this.How to check condition for username?

Thanks

Comment: As a general security best practice: you should **not** divulge to a possible attacker that the user name is correct, but just the password is wrong. This would tell an attacker that the user name is correct and he can keep hammering your system. Just say "user name or password incorrect" to both cases that you have separately now - this way, the attacker doesn't know for a fact if the user or the password (or both) is wrong.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for valuable opinion.So which lines of code should I edit to implement this

Comment: @marc S But what is to be done If I want to check only username.I am doing this only for learning purpose

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads

```
SELECT @PasswordOld = Password,@Type=ClientType,@IP=IPAddress
    FROM   Clients
    WHERE  Username = @userid
```

Wouldn't this mean that no row will be returned for a `Username` that does not exist? So, the values for `ClientType` and `IPAddress` will not get populated and will remain `NULL`, which would be the expected functionality.

However, if you want to store some value, or these fields are not nullable, assign a static value to these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct. When there is no match for the Username = @UserId , The @Type , @IP variables will be null. Since there is no record in the table for that UserName. What you can do is that in the declaration you can initiate to some default value,so that it will be inserted to table FailedLogins.

```
 DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(50)="DefaultType/NoType"
 DECLARE @IP  NVARCHAR(50)="0.0.0.1"
```

Something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

If the username is invalid it does not appear in the table `Clients` so your fields pulled from that table will also be `NULL`. To negate this you could decide to use default values for `ClientType` and `IPAddress` using static values in your declarations, but storing this would just be obsolete data and I would think changing the structure of `FailedLogins` to not store this would seem more logical.